# Developing Ruby Rails apps on small linux distro in Virtuablbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS in VirtualBox on my Macbook Pro (i7, 4gb ram) in order to do development. Shockingly it's not very snappy (quick/responsive). I want to know which distributions of Linux are small/light but can be used for Rails development in Virtualbox.

Thank you

Comment: Did you install the guest additions?

Comment: on a side note: I you need a vm dev environment I can highly recommend http://vagrantup.com. However, OSX is absolutely fine for Ruby on Rails development unless you have specific needs that *require* you to develop on another OS

Comment: i'm aware that ios is great for rails development (as i use it every day). i'd like to setup a vm because i don't want work/client projects to live on my personal machine which i need to use for working from home. i'd like to spin up my work dev machine on my personal laptop, do some work, and shut it down.

Comment: @mosch, what do you ask about guest editions? yes, i installed it to get full screen working but don't know too much else about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same using Lubuntu (the light version of ubuntu) installed on a virtual disk. Moreover, I m using a portable version of VirtualBox to have everything on a usbstick.

I ran the Lubuntu from the usbstick and began to develop some rails apps but the OI was not that great for user experience so I copied the virtual disk with lubuntu on the harddisk together with the virtualbox folder. With this setup it work realy fine!

Also, I'm using the guest additions in order to keep shared folders on the usbstick to share the projects amongst machine.

Hope it can help you in your experience.

Answer (score 0):

I use arch linux when developing. It is not designed with being “easy to use” as priority bu it is customisable for everything you need. I like the arch linux way.

Answer (score 0):

Linux VM is not necessary for developing RoR apps on OSX.

Try to google on how to develop RoR apps on native OSX.

Comment: any vm options that will allow me to do development for work while keeping my personal computer clean?